# Why do I get a GET 404 Error when I'm not even calling it as GET method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, mern

I've been getting a `GET http://localhost:3000/products/newproduct 404 (Not Found)`. And i'm not even calling it as a get method. I tried to remove all of GET method I can, but it keeps getting an error.

It happens when I click my `Add Product` inside my sidebar.

app.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css'
import Sidebar from './components/sidemenu/Sidebar'
import Topbar from './components/topbar/Topbar'
import Home from './pages/home/Home'
import NewProduct from './pages/newProduct/NewProduct'
import Product from './pages/productItem/Product'
import ProductList from './pages/productList/ProductList'
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Topbar />
      <div className="container">
        <Sidebar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" />
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          {/* Products */}
          <Route path="products">
            <Route index element={<ProductList />} />
            <Route path=":productId" element={<Product />} />
            <Route path="newproduct" element={<NewProduct />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App
```

sidebar.js

```
import {
  AttachMoney,
  BarChart,
  ChatBubbleOutline,
  DynamicFeed,
  LineStyle,
  MailOutline,
  PermIdentity,
  Report,
  Storefront,
  Timeline,
  WorkOutline,
} from '@material-ui/icons'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import './sidebar.css'

export default function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <div className="sidebarWrapper">
        <div className="sidebarMenu">
          <h3 className="sidebarTitle">Dashboard</h3>
          <ul className="sidebarList">
            <Link to="/" className="link">
              <li className="sidebarListItem active">
                <LineStyle className="sidebarIcon" />
                Home
              </li>
            </Link>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="sidebarMenu">
          <h3 className="sidebarTitle">Quick Menu</h3>
          <ul className="sidebarList">
            <Link to="/users" className="link">
              <li className="sidebarListItem">
                <PermIdentity className="sidebarIcon" />
                Users
              </li>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/products" className="link">
              <li className="sidebarListItem">
                <Storefront className="sidebarIcon" />
                Products
              </li>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/products/newproduct" className="link">
              <li className="sidebarListItem">
                <AttachMoney className="sidebarIcon" />
                Add New Products
              </li>
            </Link>
            
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

api.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
const url = 'http://localhost:5000'

export const fetchProduct = () => axios.get(`${url}/products`)
export const createProduct = (newproduct) =>
  axios.post(`${url}/products`, newproduct)
```

action.js

```
import * as api from '../api'
import { CREATE_PRODUCT, FETCH_ALL_PRODUCT } from '../constant/index'

export const getProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.fetchProduct()
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_ALL_PRODUCT, payload: data })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

export const createProduct = (product) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.createProduct(product)
    dispatch({ type: CREATE_PRODUCT, payload: data })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
  }
}
```

NewProduct.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import FileBase from 'react-file-base64'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { createProduct } from '../../actions/product'
import './newProduct.css'
const NewProduct = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [newProduct, setNewProduct] = useState({
    product: '',
    description: '',
    price: '',
  })

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setNewProduct({ ...newProduct, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  const hanldeSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(createProduct(newProduct))
  }

  return (
    <div className="newProduct">
      <h1 className="addProductTitle">New Product</h1>
      <form onSubmit={hanldeSubmit} className="addProductForm">
        <div className="addProductItem">
          <label>Image</label>
          <FileBase
            type="file"
            multiple={false}
            onDone={({ base64 }) =>
              setNewProduct({ ...newProduct, selectedFile: base64 })
            }
          />
        </div>
        <div className="addProductItem">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="product"
            name="product"
            value={newProduct.product}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="addProductItem">
          <label>Price</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            placeholder="Price"
            name="price"
            value={newProduct.price}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="addProductItem">
          <label>Description</label>
          <textarea
            name="description"
            placeholder="description"
            type="text"
            cols="4"
            rows="4"
            value={newProduct.description}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="addProductButton">
          Create
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NewProduct
```

I'm having a trouble explaining it verbally, so this is the screenshot what it looks like.

Error Image

[image: 1]

I was thinking that it is because of it recognize it as an ID in params? Which is like this..

Specific ID product

[image: 2]

Comment: Hi, Have you tried checking the port number, It's ```localhost:5000``` in your URL but your error is giving for ```localhost:3000```

Comment: Looks like this cant be found import NewProduct from './pages/newProduct/NewProduct'